# How to sort JavaRDD<Row> by multiple fields and just reserve the particular data in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input data with type `JavaRDD<Row>`.
The `Row` has two fields.

```
[
  {"fieldName":"requestId", "fieldType":"String"}, 
  {"fieldName":"price", "fieldType":"double"}
]
```

The `requestId` and `price` could be duplicated in many `Rows`. My purpose is to just reserve the `Row` with max `price` from those `Rows` with the same `requestId`. Actually, any methods will be ok even not use sort.

For example, the input is like this:

```
76044601-8029-4e09-9708-41dd125ae4bb    1676.304091136485
76044601-8029-4e09-9708-41dd125ae4bb    3898.9987591932413
ad0acb4a-100d-4624-b863-fcf275ce28db    7518.603722172683
76044601-8029-4e09-9708-41dd125ae4bb    3308.4421575701463
26f639bc-2041-435c-86da-73b997c0cc64    1737.7186292370193
beeb7fc1-2a2d-4943-8237-c281ee7c9617    4941.882928279789
26f639bc-2041-435c-86da-73b997c0cc64    1710.328581775302
```

The output data should be like this(the output order is not a problem):

```
76044601-8029-4e09-9708-41dd125ae4bb    3898.9987591932413
ad0acb4a-100d-4624-b863-fcf275ce28db    7518.603722172683
26f639bc-2041-435c-86da-73b997c0cc64    1737.7186292370193
beeb7fc1-2a2d-4943-8237-c281ee7c9617    4941.882928279789
```

Candidate method:

```
JavaRDD<Row> javaRDD = dataFrame.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, String, Row>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Row> call(Row row) {
            String key = String.valueOf(row.getAs("requestid"));
            return new Tuple2<String, Row>(key, row);
        }
    }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Row, Row, Row>() {
        @Override
        public Row call(Row row1, Row row2) throws Exception {
            double rs1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(row1.getAs("price")));
            double rs2 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(row2.getAs("price")));
            if (rs1 < rs2) {
                return row2;
            } else {
                return row1;
            }
        }
    }).map(new Function<Tuple2<String, Row>, Row>() {
        @Override
        public Row call(Tuple2<String, Row> tuple) {
            return tuple._2;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must make raw data to JavaRDD object.

And with mapToPair function, make data format as key-value type.(key : requestId, value: price)

And with reduceByKey function, choice max price as a value of key.

then the result JavaRDD is you want to expect.

Comment: I have added a candidate method according to your answer. Is that right?

Comment: yes, right. (but i didn't compile or execute the code..)

Answer (score 0):

You should use groupByKey, not reduceByKey, then sort the groupby result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to achieve this.

Just use `groupBy` and then `max`, you will get the result without parsing to `JavaRDD`.

```
df.groupBy("requestId").max("price").show();
```

**Test**

For input:

```
{"requestId": "1", "price": 10}
{"requestId": "1", "price": 15}
{"requestId": "1", "price": 19}
{"requestId": "2", "price": 20}
{"requestId": "2", "price": 21}
{"requestId": "2", "price": 26}
{"requestId": "3", "price": 30}
{"requestId": "3", "price": 38}
```

I've got:

```
+---------+----------+
|requestId|max(price)|
+---------+----------+
|        1|        19|
|        2|        26|
|        3|        38|
+---------+----------+
```